# Ajax data fetch from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to build a system in which i use javascript to first check through a table in a database and if any of the rows in the boolean column "taken" are false it loads it will then load it into the html.

The user can then drag and drop the image and it will change the boolean value to false using AJAX.

So far I have the second half done. The pill is currently just an image in the html and it has drag and drop capabilities and if it is dropped on a certain div, it currently just changes the row with id 24 to false(just a random column for testing).

This all works but i need it to fetch rows that are false and create them and then using their id number set them to false if drag and dropped. I'm not sure how to do this.
my code so far:

**action.js**

```
function doFirst(){
init();

function dropped(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to take this pill?");
    if (r == true)
    {
        //pressed ok do database stuff
        mypic.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    leftbox.style.border = '3px solid white';
        var pillid=24;
        data = "pillid="+pillid
        $.post('js/filetoupdate.php', data, function(data) {
            //Here you can get the output from PHP file which is (data) here
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //return pill to clock
    }


}
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);


function init() {
}
?>
```

**the html**

```
<div id="appframe">
  <div id="addbutton"><a href="medicineinput.php"><img src="images/addbutton.png" alt="add new medication image"/></a></div>
  <div id="message1"><h2>Todays medication</h2></div>
  <div id="message2"><h3>Drag and drop to take medication</h3></div>
  <div id="mouth"><img src="images/mouth.png" alt="mouth image"/></div>
  <div id="clock"><img src="images/clock/pill.png" alt="pill image" id="pillpic"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: also i am very new to php, javascript and ajax in general

Comment: I suggest cutting your example code down to what is specific and relevant to your problem - there's a lot of badly formatted and irrelevant code for us to read there...

Comment: I decided to add it all so you could get a feel for the context of the problem? Because im not sure if to load images in the way i want(by fetching data) if should even be like it is now?

Comment: well your question is about an Ajax call - so get rid of all that drag, drop and image manipulation code and leave your Ajax call.

Comment: I dont even have the AJAX call in there yet because im not sure how to implement it but i can try get rid of excess code.

Comment: `$.post` - its halfway down your `dropped` function and is performing a post ajax request

Comment: Oh that call is just sending data to update the table, i.e. change the boolean taken to true in the database. What i am asking is how do i go about creating another one to fetch data from the table and then create a pill image associated with each row that has a false value for "taken". So when i drag and drop i can change the row of the pill i just dragged based on its id.

Comment: we aren't here to write code for you, we're here to help you fix what you've already tried. Have a look at the jQuery AJAX Documentation and have a go: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm sure i could create the function to fetch data but what im struggling to figure out is how would i create it as an image to have an id associated with it

Comment: You'll append HTML code containing your returned data, and you'll specify an ID in that HTML...

Comment: instead of using $.post, use jquery $.ajax  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . IT is easy to use.